# How to Get the Range of Field Values in Post Method?

Tags: django-forms

How can I get the value in a Post method?

I am using:

```
print form.cleaned_data['experience']

{'max': Decimal('2'), 'min': Decimal('1')}
```

How can I get the max and min values independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `form.cleaned_data['experience']['max']`?

Comment: Thank you form.cleaned_data['experience']['max'] its working fine :)